# How to "resolve" a Flask cli command programmatically?

Tags: python, flask, command-line, command, python-click

I have a bunch of [custom Flask commands](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands) in a project, added according to the docs, e.g.:

```
import click
from flask import Flask
from flask.cli import AppGroup

app = Flask(__name__)
user_cli = AppGroup('user')

@user_cli.command('create')
@click.argument('name')
def create_user(name):
    ...

app.cli.add_command(user_cli)
```

I also need to run some of the commands in a subprocess and log some information. How can I "resolve" a command given a string like `'flask user create demo'` and get the name of the command **without any arguments**, i.e. `'flask user create'` in this case? I can see that `app.cli` has a `resolve_command()` method but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume Flask's CLI group is just a wrapper around the standard click cli group.
As such, if you want to get the name and the command path, you can do this inside `create_user`:

```py
@user_cli.command('create')
@click.argument('name')
def create_user(name):
    ctx = click.get_current_context()
    print(ctx.command.name)
    print(ctx.command_path)
```

Furthermore, to resolve a command based on the name, you can use the `get_command` method available on a `Context`:
https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.MultiCommand.get_command

I've also added an `app` command that resolves a command, using `resolve_command`. This might help you achieve what you want. What is the use case for what you're trying to achieve, if you don't mind me asking?

```py
@app.cli.command('resolve')
@click.argument('name', nargs=-1)
def resolve(name):
    group, *command = app.cli.resolve_command(click.get_current_context(), name)
    print(group)
    print(command)
```

```sh
❯ flask resolve user create
user
[<AppGroup user>, ('create',)]
```

Comment: I need to do it outside of the actual command handler. How can I "resolve" a command with just the `app` instance (as in the OP)?

Comment: Not overly familiar with Flask outside a few very basic things I have tried. Would you mind posting an example application, so I can easily replicate the setup?

Comment: I think you can use the minimal application from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) and just add a [custom command](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands) (with a group) to it.

Comment: Then I'm doing something wrong cause Flask complains about missing env vars and files. I'll let you know once I get it working

Comment: You may need to set the `FLASK_APP` envariable, e.g. if you put the code in the file `hello.py`, then run `export FLASK_APP=hello.py`

Comment: @planetp i've added a resolve command case, you might be able to use that code to achieve what you want

Comment: `> What is the use case for what you're trying to achieve?` I need to log the command that is being run, but omit any arguments as they might contain PII. The command is then run in a subprocess.